# Link error "unresolved external(s)" with custom header includes

Tags: c

I haven't had any real "need" for it until recently, but I'm trying to figure out how dividing functions into multiple headers/files works. Even the simplest thing doesn't seem to work as I thought it would.

I have the following code:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hdr.h"

int main(void)
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

**hdr.h**

```
int test(void);
```

**hdr.c**

```
int test(void)
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

When I try to compile this with [Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) (*cc*), I get the error "unresolved external(s)":

```
main.c
polink.exe main.obj
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '_test'.
POLINK: fatal error: 1 unresolved external(s).
```

The command line I use is:

```
cc -x main.c
```

Why is this? Can I change something in the code to avoid touching the command line? Or do I always have to build custom header stuff separately first?

Comment: You haven't compiled test.c so it can't be linked

Comment: @Vorsprung is there any way to have **hdr.c** automatically be included in the compilation process through the source code?

Comment: sure ``#include "test.c"``

Comment: But the answer below is a better solution. My tip would be learn how Makefiles work

Comment: Do not `#include "test.c"`...  Not sure why this was even suggested.

Comment: Yeah, `#include`ing **.c** files seems ill-advised, so I'll probably refrain from that. But it feels kind of silly to have to specify the respective source files for all the headers when they're already (indirectly) `#include`d in the main source code.

Answer (score 2):

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hdr.h"

int main(void)
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

hdr.h

```
int test(void);
```

hdr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>    // add header file
int test(void)
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

compile with command:

```
cc main.c hdr.c
```

then you will find a file named : a.out, run it with command:

```
./a.out
```

or you also can like this:

```
cc -g -o main main.c hdr.c
./main
```